# Add Rails Engine to Procfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, rails-engines, foreman

The desired scenario is to run an Engine on a separate dyno or dynos when deploying to Heroku. The Procfile would look something like:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
engine: TODO
```

This way we could scale the dynos used by the engine easily: `heroku ps:scale engine=3`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/components-in-rails/zQTLPZGqIaI

Ended up following the advice from Enrico Teotti on this post: http://teotti.com/feature-flagging-portions-of-your-ruby-on-rails-application-with-engines/

Basically we need to feature flag our engine. In `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  case ENV['APP_RUNNING_MODE']
  when 'my_engine'
    mount MyEngine::Engine => "/my_engine"
  else
    # rest of the routes...
  end
end
```

The `Procfile` will look like:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
engine: APP_RUNNING_MODE=my_engine bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
```

Comment: Very interesting solution! How did you manage to expose both rails servers on the same port to become accessible outside? As a side comment, a nice feature would be if the <process_type>: part of the Procfile would be available at runtime within a environment variable so you wouldn't need to make it explicit like in APP_RUNNING_MODE. Keep Rocking!

Comment: hey @fagiani sorry for the late reply. Just checked and we're using the same port but on different heroku apps.